# How to automaticly update parent after condition is fulfilled?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want make that after all project tasks are flagged as completed, my project automaticly change from not_completed to completed. I did make working method but it is very inefficient.

```
def project_toggle
  @projects_ids = Project.pluck(:id)
  @projects_ids.each do |cond|
    if Task.find_project_tasks(cond).pluck(:task_status).include?('not_complete')
      Project.find(cond).update(project_status: :'not complete')
    else
      Project.find(cond).update(project_status: :complete)
    end
  end
end
```

After that I used `joins` and its way more efficient but I don't know how to make it completed projects because its displaying only if all status is false.

```
Project.joins(:tasks).where(tasks: { task_status: false }).where(user_id: current_user)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you're trying to mark the parent (`Project`) completed when all the children (`Task`s) are complete. I've had to do this many times, but this logic belongs in the Model instead of the controller.

Assuming your `Task` has a boolean attribute called `complete`, Rails will automatically generate the `complete?` method (note the question mark).

Just add a `complete?` method to your Project that checks if all Tasks are `complete?`.

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord`

  ...

  # Have all tasks been completed?
  def complete?
    tasks.all? { |t| t.complete? }
  end

  ...

end
```

Then, to make sure if your project is completed, just run `project.complete?`

This is better than adding a column to your `projects` table, because you don't want to duplicate data. You can infer if a `project` is complete from the `tasks` data already, and this way you won't risk your `projects` table accidentally falling out of sync with the tasks. Especially if you've marked a project as completed, and then add a task later.